# Calling functionality from Oracle ADF application, Web services or something else?

Tags: web-services, oracle, oracle-adf

My client is using functionality from 3rd party oracle ADF applications manually. That functionality is calculation of insurance price for various types of vehicles. They enter data in forms and print a report. They have 4 different 3rd party systems and after submission in all 4 systems they are comparing reports and search for best insurance deals. It's slow and these reports are all different and hard to compare.

My task is propose a way how can we make one application for data input and reports and what that 3rd parties must do on their end. That application would communicate insurance data with theese 3rd party application, and get prices and other data. They are using Oracle ADF application, and I am not sure what is the most efficient way to do that communication ? Are the Web Services way to go ? Or there is some other way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the functionality is coded in PLSQL, then you can call PLSQL directly from the ADF BC layer (EO).
Or, yes, you can expose the functionality as a WS and consume this from the ADF BC layer either wrapped in a POJO or as a data control in its own right, exposed on a JSF page.